# XmlDocument difficulties returning specific nodes/elements

Tags: xml-namespaces, xmldocument

first post.  I hope it meets with the rules of asking questions.

I'm in a bit of bother with an xml document (its an API returned Xml). Now it uses a multitude of internet (http based) security measures which I have worked thru and I am now able to return the the top tier of nodes that are not nested.

however there are a few nodes which are nested under these and I need to return some of these values.

I'm set on using XMLDocument to do this, and I'm not interested in using XPath.

I should also note that I'm using the .Net 4.5 environment.

**Example XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
 <results>
    <Info xmlns="http://xmlns.namespace">
      <title>This Title</title>
    <ref>
      <SetId>317</SetId>
    </ref>
    <source>
        <name>file.xxx</name>
        <type>thisType</type>
        <hash>cc7b99599c1bebfc4b8f12e47aba3f76</hash>
        <pers>65.97602</pers>
        <time>02:20:02.8527777</time>
    </source>
    ....... Continuation which is same as above
```

Ok so above is the Xml that gets returned from the API, now, I can return title node no problem. What I would also like to return is any of the node values in the  Element, for example the pers node value.  But I only want to return one (as there are many in the existing xml further down)

Please note that there is an xmlns in the Info node which may not be allowing me to return the values.

So here is my code

```
using (var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse())
        {
            //Get the response stream
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                if (stream != null)
                {
                    var xDoc = new XmlDocument();

                    var nsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(xDoc.NameTable);
                    nsm.AddNamespace("ns", XmlNamespace);

                    //Read the response stream
                    using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
                    {
                        // This is straight forward, we just need to read the XML document and return the bits we need.
                        xDoc.Load(xmlReader);
                        XmlElement root = xDoc.DocumentElement;
                        var cNodes = root.SelectNodes("/results/ns:Info", nsm);

                        //Create a new instance of Info so that we can store any data found in the Info Properties.
                        var info = new Info();

                        // Now we have a collection of Info objects
                        foreach (XmlNode node in cNodes)
                        {
                            // Do some parsing or other relevant filtering here
                            var title = node["title"];
                            if (title != null)
                            {
                                info.Title = title.InnerText;
                                _logger.Info("This is the title returned ############# {0}", info.Title);
                            }

                            //This is the bit that is killing me as i can't return the any values in the of the sub nodes
                            XmlNodeList sourceNodes = node.SelectNodes("source"); 
                            foreach (XmlNode sn in sourceNodes)
                            {
                                XmlNode source = sn.SelectSingleNode("source");
                                {
                                    var pers = root["pers"];
                                    if (pers != null) info.pers = pers.InnerText;
                                    _logger.Info("############FPS = {0}", info.pers);
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

So I finally figured it out.

Here is the code that gets the subnodes.  Basically I wasn't using my namespace identifier or my namespace for returning subnodes within the "Source" node.

For anybody else in this situation,

When you declare your name space there are to parts to it, a namespace identifier which is anything you want it to be in my case I chose "ns" and then the actual namespace in the XML file which is prefixed by xmlns and will contain something like for example: "http://xmlns.mynamespace".

So when searching subnodes inside the top level you need to declare these namespaces for the main node of the subnode you want to get.

```
// get the <source> subnode using the namespace to returns all <source> values 
                            var source = node.SelectSingleNode("ns:source", nsm);
                            if (source != null)
                            {
                                info.SourceType = source["type"].InnerText;
                                info.Pers = source["pers"].InnerText;

                                _logger.Info("This SourceNode is {0}", info.SourceType);
                                _logger.Info("This PersNode is {0}", info.FramesPerSecond);
                            }
```

I hope this helps somebody else that's chasing their tails as I have.

Thanks